# SbtNativePackager "No EXPOSE directive found in Dockerfile"

Tags: docker, sbt-native-packager

I am using play 2.2.

Here is my build.sbt

```
    import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
    import NativePackagerKeys._

    name := "test"

    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    maintainer in Docker := "First Last <****@gmail.com>"

    dockerExposedPorts in Docker := Seq(9000)

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      javaJdbc,
      javaEbean,
      cache,
      filters
    )
```

When I run deploy:stage, EXPOSE directive is missing in the generated Dockerfile.

Here is the generated Dockerfile

```
    FROM dockerfile/java
    MAINTAINER "First Last <****@gmail.com>"
    ADD files /
    WORKDIR /opt/docker
    RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon", "."]
    USER daemon
    ENTRYPOINT ["bin/test"]
    CMD []
```

Comment: What version of sbt-native-packager are you using?

Comment: I am using sbt-native-packager version 0.8.0-M1

Comment: Try removing the "in Docker" from dockerExposedPorts. I'm afraid it's not scoped

Comment: I tried removing the "in Docker" from dockerExposedPorts. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Where are your Play settings defined? The ordering is very important, the Play settings *must* be initialised before your changes are added (otherwise, the settings will be reset to defaults).